# c# TimeSpan Converting Minutes to Hours

Tags: c#, timespan

I am converting minutes into hours. So if I have `minutes = 12534`. The result should be `208:54`. The below code fails to bring this result.

```
TimeSpan spWorkMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12534);
string workHours = spWorkMin.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
Console.WriteLine(workHours);
```

The result is `16:54`.

How to get it correct?

Comment: time span convert into days to that's way you are not getting correct result.

Comment: You should give more examples. What output do you expect for 1, 9, 10, 59, 60, 61 minutes? It's important for correct zero padding in the format, if needed.

Comment: A complete test set would also include 1440, 6000, 594000, 594001 minutes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct way to use is not using the `ToString` overload of `DateTime` – because there is no possibility to show the `TotalHours` there –  but the `string.Format` method:

```
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (int)spWorkMin.TotalHours, spWorkMin.Minutes);
```

Comment: TotalHours is a double, this would return "208.9:54" for the provided input.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy I have now changed the `format` to always display two digits.

Answer (score 18):

```
var totalMinutes = 12534;
Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{1:00}", totalMinutes / 60, totalMinutes % 60);
```

Or

```
var totalMinutes = 12534;
var time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(totalMinutes);
Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{1:00}", (int)time.TotalHours, time.Minutes);
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/gYEsj2 to play with this

Comment: This would format incorrectly for number of minutes <10

Comment: var totalMinutes = 1; // 0:1

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy - Indeed. Fixed

Answer (score 4):

You need use `TimeSpan.TotalHours` Property

The [TotalHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx) property represents whole and fractional hours, whereas the `Hours` property represents whole hours.

```
    TimeSpan spWorkMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12534);
    string workHours = spWorkMin.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
    Console.WriteLine(spWorkMin.TotalHours);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/JRCLra

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier `hh` will show the hour part, which is not the total hours. You have to manually create a string using `TotalHours` cast into ints to show it as you want and add the minutes to that.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN documentation:

> The "hh" custom format specifier outputs the value of the TimeSpan::Hours property, which represents the number of whole hours in the time interval that is not counted as part of its day component.

One quick way of getting the result you want would be something like the following:

```
TimeSpan spWorkMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12534);
string workHours = string.Format("{0}:{1:00}", (int)spWorkMin.TotalHours, spWorkMin.Minutes);
Console.WriteLine(workHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan spWorkMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12534);
string workHours = string.Format("{0}:{1}", (int)spWorkMin.TotalHours, spWorkMin.Minutes);
Console.WriteLine(workHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I use this:

```
public static double MinutsTohHours(int Minuti)
    {
        double Tempo = 0;
            Tempo = ((double)(Minuti % 60) / 100);
            var n = (double)Minuti / 60;
            return Math.Floor((double)Minuti / 60) + Tempo;
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

var days = 1; 
var hours = 23; //max 23
var min = 12; //max 59

var TotalMin = (days*24*60)+(hours*60)+min;

Console.WriteLine("TotalMins "+ TotalMin);

//return back to the original days,hours,minutes

var Days = (TotalMin/(24*60));
var _minutes = (TotalMin%(60*60));
var Hours = (_minutes/60);
var Minutes = _minutes - (Hours*60);

Console.WriteLine($"{Days} , {Hours} , {Minutes}");
```